# Duplicate a remote session in terminal in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, session, linux-terminal

How do I duplicate a remote session in the Linux (Ubuntu) terminal? For example, if I have an SSH session open, how can I duplicate this session in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

First install [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Now open your ssh connection, e.g. (in my case, using a private key .pem file):

```
ssh -i ./this/is/a/path.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x
```

Start a screen session:

```
screen
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd> (where c is pressed after you let go of pressing Ctrl and a simultaneously [this will open a new window.])

Either retype the command used to initiate your SSH connection, or press <kbd>↑</kbd> and select the command used to initiate your SSH connection.

Voila! You've just duplicated a remote SSH session in the terminal!

To switch between windows use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd> (where n is pressed after you let go of pressing Ctrl and a simultaneously.)

For a more in-depth guide on how to use screen, visit [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-screen-command-howto.html).